# Find the maximum between aggregate values in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a PostgreSQL database and an web app built in Node.js.

I have a table `cases` like that:

```
  disease   |                country                | year |  number   |  rate
------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----------+--------
 Diphtheria | Austria                               | 1989 |    190.00 |   2.47
 Tetanus    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN 
 Pertussis  | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Measles    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Mumps      | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Rubella    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Diphtheria | Belgium                               | 1989 |    180.00 |   2.42
 Tetanus    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      5.00 |   0.04  
 Pertussis  | Belgium                               | 1989 |      1.00 |   0.01
 Measles    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Mumps      | Belgium                               | 1989 |   2052.00 |  50.00
 Rubella    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Diphtheria | Austria                               | 1990 |      5.00 |   0.01
 Tetanus    | Austria                               | 1990 |    152.00 |   2.41 
 Pertussis  | Austria                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Measles    | Austria                               | 1990 |    850.00 |   3.55
 Mumps      | Austria                               | 1990 |       NaN |    NaN
 Rubella    | Austria                               | 1990 |     55.00 |   3.00
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Diphtheria | Belgium                               | 1990 |    191.00 |   2.48
 Tetanus    | Belgium                               | 1990 |     20.00 |   2.00
 Pertussis  | Belgium                               | 1990 |      5.00 |   0.40
 Measles    | Belgium                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Mumps      | Belgium                               | 1990 |      0.40 |   0.02
 Rubella    | Belgium                               | 1990 |     85.00 |   6.08
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1990 |     10.00 |   0.60
 ...        | ...                                   |  ... |       ... |    ...
```

In total there are 8040 rows, 7 different disease values, 32 different country values and 36 different year values.

I have to combine some values based on the disease and find the maximum value.
For examples, I need to combine Diphtheria, Tetanus and Pertussis in a new value (called DTP) whose number (and rate) is the sum of the single values.
The same thing with Measles, Mumps and Rubella that become MMR.
The other values (Polio) remains as it is now.

So, this is the intermediate step:

```
  disease   |                country                | year |  number   |  rate
------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----------+--------
 DTP        | Austria                               | 1989 |    190.00 |   2.47
 MMR        | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 DTP        | Belgium                               | 1989 |    186.00 |   2.47
 MMR        | Belgium                               | 1989 |   2052.00 |  50.00
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 DTP        | Austria                               | 1990 |    157.00 |   2.42
 MMR        | Austria                               | 1990 |    905.00 |   6.55
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 DTP        | Belgium                               | 1990 |    216.00 |   4.88
 MMR        | Belgium                               | 1990 |     85.40 |   7.00
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1990 |     10.00 |   0.60
 ...        | ...                                   |  ... |       ... |    ...
```

Summing values, I considered `NaN` as `0`.

After that I need to have the max value for each different disease element, so:

```
max DTP number =  216.00
max DTP rate = 4.88
max MMR number = 2052.00
max MMR rate = 5.00
max Polio number = 10.00
max Polio rate = 0.60
```

What I need is the maximum values, so I don't mind creating the intermediate table. It'ok both if it is created or not.

How can I do?

Comment: I think you must have intermediate table. If some groups changes it would be easier to modify table than a few functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
WITH intermediate_table AS
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS DTP_NUMBER,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS DTP_RATE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS MMR_NUMBER,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS MMR_RATE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS Polio_NUMBER,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS Polio_RATE,
        country,
        year
    FROM cases
    GROUP BY country, year
)
SELECT MAX(DTP_NUMBER) AS MAX_DTP_NUMBER,
    MAX(DTP_RATE) AS MAX_DTP_RATE,
    MAX(MMR_NUMBER) AS MAX_MMR_NUMBER,
    MAX(MMR_RATE) AS MAX_MMR_RATE,
    MAX(Polio_NUMBER) AS MAX_Polio_NUMBER,
    MAX(Polio_RATE) AS MAX_Polio_RATE
FROM intermediate_table;
```

Use `ROUND` if needed in your query.

Comment: I execute your query and I get all the resultin values are NaN. I think is dued to **Asssume that NaN means NULL**. Am I right?

Comment: @ColdFish Yes, I have updated my answer for that `NaN`