# Add rows in a table formed as a sum of others

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have already posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229551/find-the-maximum-between-aggregate-values-in-a-table) to this one but now the problem is another.

I have a a table `cases` like that:

```
  disease   |                country                | year |  number   |  rate
------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----------+--------
 Diphtheria | Austria                               | 1989 |    190.00 |   2.47
 Tetanus    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN 
 Pertussis  | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Measles    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Mumps      | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Rubella    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Diphtheria | Belgium                               | 1989 |    180.00 |   2.42
 Tetanus    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      5.00 |   0.04  
 Pertussis  | Belgium                               | 1989 |      1.00 |   0.01
 Measles    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Mumps      | Belgium                               | 1989 |   2052.00 |  50.00
 Rubella    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Diphtheria | Austria                               | 1990 |      5.00 |   0.01
 Tetanus    | Austria                               | 1990 |    152.00 |   2.41 
 Pertussis  | Austria                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Measles    | Austria                               | 1990 |    850.00 |   3.55
 Mumps      | Austria                               | 1990 |       NaN |    NaN
 Rubella    | Austria                               | 1990 |     55.00 |   3.00
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Diphtheria | Belgium                               | 1990 |    191.00 |   2.48
 Tetanus    | Belgium                               | 1990 |     20.00 |   2.00
 Pertussis  | Belgium                               | 1990 |      5.00 |   0.40
 Measles    | Belgium                               | 1990 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Mumps      | Belgium                               | 1990 |      0.40 |   0.02
 Rubella    | Belgium                               | 1990 |     85.00 |   6.08
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1990 |     10.00 |   0.60
 ...        | ...                                   |  ... |       ... |    ...
```

and I want to add some rows calculated as the sum of some values.
I try to explain myself better.

The following query calculates the sum of the number and rate values of the values of diptheria, tetanus, pertussis, (and other..) and create a row with the summed values.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS DTP_NUMBER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS DTP_RATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS MMR_NUMBER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS MMR_RATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS Polio_NUMBER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS Polio_RATE,
    country,
    year
FROM cases
GROUP BY country, year;
```

Result of execution:

I would like to add these results to the cases table, in order to get something like this:

```
  disease   |                country                | year |  number   |  rate
------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----------+--------
 Diphtheria | Austria                               | 1989 |    190.00 |   2.47
 Tetanus    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN 
 Pertussis  | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Measles    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Mumps      | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Rubella    | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 Polio      | Austria                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 DTP        | Austria                               | 1989 |    190.00 |   2.47
 MMR        | Austria                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Diphtheria | Belgium                               | 1989 |    180.00 |   2.42
 Tetanus    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      5.00 |   0.04  
 Pertussis  | Belgium                               | 1989 |      1.00 |   0.01
 Measles    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Mumps      | Belgium                               | 1989 |   2052.00 |  50.00
 Rubella    | Belgium                               | 1989 |      0.00 |   0.00
 Polio      | Belgium                               | 1989 |       NaN |    NaN
 DTP        | Belgium                               | 1989 |    186.00 |   2.47
 MMR        | Belgium                               | 1989 |   2052.00 |  50.00
 ...        | ...                                   |  ... |       ... |    ...
```

How can I do?
I had thought about using a query like:

```
    INSERT INTO cases (column names) 
    VALUES (
            SELECT 
            SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS DTP_NUMBER,
            SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS DTP_RATE,
            SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS MMR_NUMBER,
            SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS MMR_RATE,
            SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS Polio_NUMBER,
            SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS Polio_RATE,
            country,
            year
        FROM cases
        GROUP BY country, year
    );
```

but what I have to place in column names?

## EDIT 1

My cases table is created in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cases (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    disease VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
    number NUMERIC(20, 2) NOT NULL,
    rate NUMERIC(20, 2) NULL,
    UNIQUE (disease, country, year, number));
```

When I run the query created by *Pham X. Bach*, I get:

```
ERROR:  ERROR:  null values in the "number" column violate the non-null constraint
DETAIL:  The error line contains (8077, DTP, Poland, 2015, null, null).
```

If I change my query that create table in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cases (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    disease VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
    number NUMERIC(20, 2),
    rate NUMERIC(20, 2),
    UNIQUE (disease, country, year, number));
```

and then I execute your query, I get:

```
Error Message ERROR: A duplicate key value violates the unique constraint "cases_disease_country_year_number_key"
DETAIL:  The key (disease, country, year, number)=(Polio, United Kingdom, 1987, 0.00) yet exists.
```

If I run query of *Anadi Sharma*, I get a syntax error in line 3.

Comment: You have to place the column names of the _cases_ table

Comment: @schlonzo Ok but the result of the query has a different structure from my `cases` table

Comment: The order of the column names doesn't matter as long as you provide all the column names, that doen't accept null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
INSERT INTO cases (
    disease, country, year, 
    number, 
    rate
) 
SELECT 
    'DTP' AS disease, country, year,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END), 'NaN') AS number,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END), 'NaN') AS rate
FROM cases
GROUP BY country, year
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'MMR' AS disease, country, year,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END), 'NaN') AS number,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END), 'NaN') AS rate
FROM cases
GROUP BY country, year
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Polio_Sum' AS disease, country, year,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END), 'NaN') AS number,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END), 'NaN') AS rate
FROM cases
GROUP BY country, year
;
```

Comment: Thanks but there are some problems. I update my main message.

Comment: @ColdFish That is `NaN` problem again as in your previous question. See my updated answer.

Comment: I get always `Error Message ERROR: A duplicate key value violates the unique constraint` `"cases_disease_country_year_number_key"
DETAIL:  The key (disease, country, year, number)=(Polio, United Kingdom, 1987, 0.00) yet exists.`...

Comment: @ColdFish That is because of your group naming, not error from query. It's OK when you use group `DTP` and `MMR` because their name are unique. But `Polio` group is same name as your existing data `Polio`, so when you try inserting it, it raise `duplicate key value violates`. In the query, if you change `'Polio' AS disease` to `'Polio_SUM' AS disease` then it'll be ok.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select query is not structured as `cases` table. You should use union to resolve this. Try using following query:

```
INSERT INTO cases 
    SELECT 
        disease,
        country,
        year,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS number,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Diphtheria', 'Tetanus', 'Pertussis') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS rate            
    FROM cases
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        disease,
        country,
        year,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS number,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Rubella') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS rate            
    FROM cases
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        disease,
        country,
        year,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND number <> 'NaN' THEN number END) AS number,
        SUM(CASE WHEN disease IN ('Polio') AND rate <> 'NaN' THEN rate END) AS rate            
    FROM cases
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: @ColdFish This query has 2 error, first is wrong syntax `INSERT INTO .. VALUES SELECT ... FROM`, second is the `not a GROUP BY expression`. You should post link to your previous question so others could understand your `DTP`, `MMR`, `Polio` group

Comment: Its my bad! I had the wrong syntax. Please try running now! Thanks! :)

Comment: @AnadiSharma Ok, now I get `ERROR:  column "cases.disease" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an   aggregate function`. Sorry but I I know very little sql..

Comment: @PhamX.Bach You are right! I add the link to my previous question in the message

Comment: @ColdFish Yeah this error makes sense, my bad again! I just edited my answer.